# Allow anonymous authentication permitAll() in case of custom exception is thrown from custom Spring-security filter

Tags: spring, spring-security

My use case is that if my authorization server is down(5xx errors returned from authz server) I need to send the same error code and response to the client.
I am using spring-security 5.7.2.
This is my use case.
/authserver is the authz server endpoint which could return 500

```
 @Test
  void testAuthenticateWhenAnonymous() {

    final String merchantId = RandomString.make();
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    // we should also allow anonymous authentication when authz fails
    wm.stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("/authserver"))
                    .willReturn(aResponse()
                                    .withStatus(500)));

    final ResponseEntity<Void> response2 = restTemplate.exchange(
        "/test-anonymous",
        HttpMethod.GET,
        entity,
        Void.class);
    assertThat(response2.getStatusCode())
        .isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
```

This is how I configured my spring security for-

1. permitAll

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .apply(configurer)
          .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/test-anonymous")
            .permitAll()
          .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .accessDecisionManager(new CustomAccessDecisionManager(Arrays.asList(
              new WebExpressionVoter(),
              new RoleVoter(),
              new AuthenticatedVoter()), new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl()));
    }
```

2. Other use case

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    for (final CustomWebSecurityConfigurer configurer : configurers) {
      configurer.configure(http);
    }
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .accessDecisionManager(new CustomAccessDecisionManager(Arrays.asList(
            new WebExpressionVoter(),
            new RoleVoter(),
            new AuthenticatedVoter()), new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl()))
        .and()
          .csrf().disable()
          .cors()
        .and()
          .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
          .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(globalSecurityExceptionHandler())
            .accessDeniedHandler(globalSecurityExceptionHandler());
  }
```

I had to write Custom AccessDecisionManager as default one was throwing 403 errors from ExceptionTranslationFilter because WebExpressionVoter was throwing AccessDeniedError.

I am throwing the 5xx errors in my Custom Filter class like this-

```
package com.*.security.*;

import com.*.*.ServletRequestContext;
import com.*.*.authentication.*;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CustomAuthenticationWebFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {



  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
  private final CustomAuthenticationResolver resolver;


  public CustomAuthenticationWebFilter(
      final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
      final CustomAuthenticationResolver resolver) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.resolver = resolver;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response,
      FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (requiresAuthentication()) {
      Optional<CustomAuthentication> op = extract(request, response);
      if (op.isPresent()) {
        CustomAuthentication authentication = op.get();
        try {
          if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
            final Authentication authResult = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
            setAuthentication(authResult);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
          }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          LOGGER.warn("Failed to authenticate request", ex);
        }
      } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
    }
  }

  Optional<CustomAuthentication> extract(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    return resolver.get(ServletRequestContext.of(request)).blockOptional();
  }

  void setAuthentication(final Authentication authentication) {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
  }

  boolean requiresAuthentication() {
    final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated();
  }

}
```

`doFilterInternal` calls `op.get()` and it calls the authz server. Below is the code.
I am trying the exception in `.onErrorResume()..`

```
public Mono<CustomAuthentication> get(GenericRequestContext context) {
    return myService.getReactive(context)
        .flatMap(capabilities -> {
          final CustomPrincipal principal = principalResolver.get(myService);
          final CustomAuthenticationToken credentials = credentialsResolver.get(myService);
          final Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = grantedAuthoritiesResolver.get(myService);
          // if we are using strict mode, need to verify that there is at least 1 valid credential
      
          return Mono.just(new CustomAuthentication(principal, credentials, authorities));
        })
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
    
          if (throwable instanceof ApiException) {
            ApiException apiException = (ApiException) throwable;

            if (apiException.getHttpStatusCode().is5xxServerError()) {

              // CustomAccessDecisionManager as part of ICPE-242
              return Mono.error(apiException);
            }
          }
          return Mono.empty();
        });
  }
```

I then added CustomAccessDecisionManager to check if error is of 5xx type then set it in the response.

```
public class CustomAccessDecisionManager extends AffirmativeBased implements AccessDecisionManager {


  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver;

  public CustomAccessDecisionManager(List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> decisionVoters,
                                         AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver) {
    super(decisionVoters);
    this.trustResolver = trustResolver;
  }

  @Override
  public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes)
      throws AccessDeniedException {

    // Perform the authentication server check here
    if (null != object && object instanceof FilterInvocation && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(attributes)) {
      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = ((FilterInvocation) object).getResponse();
        try {
          if (trustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) && "permitAll".equals(attributes.iterator().next().toString())) {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(200);
            httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush();
          } else {
            if (null!= httpServletResponse && HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR != httpServletResponse.getStatus()) {
              super.decide(authentication, object, attributes);
            } else {
              httpServletResponse.getWriter().write("{\"error\": \"Internal error\"}");
              httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush();
              throw new ApiException("Internal Server Error");
            }
          }
        } catch(IOException e){
          LOGGER.error("Error writing response", e);
        }


      }
    }
  }
```

This code works fine except for permitAll endpoint. I tried adding below check to set 200 status code to response object if the endpoint is anonymous but this also fails. i.e. when the authz server sends 200, then attributes has **permitAll** expression, else it returns **authenticated** expression.
Also `isAnonymous` check fails if the use case is when any endpoint doesn't requires any authentication
  `if (trustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) && "permitAll".equals(attributes.iterator().next().toString())) { httpServletResponse.setStatus(200); httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush(); }`